# How to get a biblatex bibliography style similar with \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} in natbib

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

When I use natbib and set bibliography style as

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

The Reference Style looks like this:
[image]

Now I use biblatex and I use the following command:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
            backend=biber,
            maxnames = 3, minnames = 3,
            hyperref=true, natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

The reference style is as followed:
[image]

I am wondering how to set bibliography style just like abbrvnat in natbib. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It would be much easier if the two pictures would feature the same references. And more importantly: please add an MWE, including a `.bib` file to play with.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Be sure to run `\usepackage[style=trad-abbrv,natbib]{biblatex}` and `\cite` if you want numeric-style citation callouts, and `\usepackage[style=trad-abbrv,natbib,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}` along with `\citet` or `\citep` if you want authoryear-style citation callouts.